# OpenMP: parallel for doesn't do anything

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to make a parallel version of SIFT algorithm in OpenCV.

In particular in `sift.cpp`:

```
static void calcDescriptors(const std::vector<Mat>& gpyr, const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                            Mat& descriptors, int nOctaveLayers, int firstOctave )
{
...
#pragma omp parallel for
for( size_t i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++ )
{
...
    calcSIFTDescriptor(img, ptf, angle, size*0.5f, d, n, descriptors.ptr<float>((int)i));
...    
}
```

Gives already a speed-up from `84ms` to `52ms` on a quad-core machine. It doesn't scale so much, but it's already a good result for adding 1 line of codes.

Anyway most of the computation inside the loop is performed by `calcSIFTDescriptor()`, but anyway it takes on average `100us`. So most of the computation time is given by the **really high** number of times that `calcSIFTDescriptor()` is called (thousands of times). So accomulating all these `100us` results in several `ms`.

Anyway, I'm trying to optimize the `calcSIFTDescriptor()` performance. In particular the code is devide between two `for` and the following one take on average `60us`:

```
for( k = 0; k < len; k++ )
{
    float rbin = RBin[k], cbin = CBin[k];
    float obin = (Ori[k] - ori)*bins_per_rad;
    float mag = Mag[k]*W[k];

    int r0 = cvFloor( rbin );
    int c0 = cvFloor( cbin );
    int o0 = cvFloor( obin );
    rbin -= r0;
    cbin -= c0;
    obin -= o0;

    if( o0 < 0 )
        o0 += n;
    if( o0 >= n )
        o0 -= n;

    // histogram update using tri-linear interpolation
    float v_r1 = mag*rbin, v_r0 = mag - v_r1;
    float v_rc11 = v_r1*cbin, v_rc10 = v_r1 - v_rc11;
    float v_rc01 = v_r0*cbin, v_rc00 = v_r0 - v_rc01;
    float v_rco111 = v_rc11*obin, v_rco110 = v_rc11 - v_rco111;
    float v_rco101 = v_rc10*obin, v_rco100 = v_rc10 - v_rco101;
    float v_rco011 = v_rc01*obin, v_rco010 = v_rc01 - v_rco011;
    float v_rco001 = v_rc00*obin, v_rco000 = v_rc00 - v_rco001;

    int idx = ((r0+1)*(d+2) + c0+1)*(n+2) + o0;
    hist[idx] += v_rco000;
    hist[idx+1] += v_rco001;
    hist[idx+(n+2)] += v_rco010;
    hist[idx+(n+3)] += v_rco011;
    hist[idx+(d+2)*(n+2)] += v_rco100;
    hist[idx+(d+2)*(n+2)+1] += v_rco101;
    hist[idx+(d+3)*(n+2)] += v_rco110;
    hist[idx+(d+3)*(n+2)+1] += v_rco111;
}
```

So I tried to add `#pragma omp parallel for private(k)` before it, and the weird thing happens: **nothing happens!!!**

Introducing this `parallel for` make the code computation on average `53ms` (against `52ms` of before). I would have expected one or more of the following results:

1. Taking `>52ms` given by the overhead of a new `parallel for`
2. Taking `<52ms` given by the gain obtained by the `parallel for`
3. Some sort of inconsistency in the result, since as you can see the shared vector `hist` is updated concurrently. Nothing of this happens: the result is still correct and no `atomic` or `critical` are used.

I'm an OpenMP newbie, but from I see is like this inner `parllel for` is like ignored. Why this happens?

**NOTE:** all the reported times are the average time with the same input for 10.000 times.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to remove the first `parallel for`, leaving the one in `calcSIFTDescriptor` and it happened was I was expecting: **inconsistency** has been observed due to the lack of any thread-safety mechanism. Introducing `#pragma omp critical(dataupdate)` before updating `hist` gave consistency again **but now performances are horribles:** `245ms` on average.

I think that this is because of the overhead given by the `parallel for` in `calcSIFTDescriptor`, which is not worth for parallelize `30us`.

**BUT THE QUESTION STILL REMAINS:** why the first version (with two `parallel for`) didn't produce **any change** (both in performance and consistency)?

Comment: So, you are executing outer loop in parallel, making every core to get own `calcSIFTDescriptor` to execute, and then you want to distribute inner loop over... what? All cores are already busy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you posted it just one second before my **UPDATE** (check it out). Anyway as I said I'm an OpenMP newbie, but inner `parallel for` is a common practice. In fact ` #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)` is introuced exactly for two inner `for` instructions (as explained [here](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Abstract) under "The collapse clause" section)

Comment: (@Revolver_Ocelot BTW I have to say this: Snake? SNAAAAAAAKE)

Comment: Ok I found out what do you by myself and I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer by myself: the second (nested) `parallel for` doesn't make *any* effect for the reason described here:

> OpenMP parallel regions can be nested inside each other. If nested
>   parallelism is disabled, then the new team created by a thread
>   encountering a parallel construct inside a parallel region consists
>   only of the encountering thread. If nested parallelism is enabled,
>   then the new team may consist of more than one thread.

So since the first `parallel for` takes all the possible thread, the second one has as team the encountering thread itself. So nothing happens.

Cheers to myself!

Comment: Nested parallelism is disabled by default and one has to explicitly enable it by either setting `OMP_NESTED` in the environment to true or by calling `omp_set_nested(1);`.